# npm error when I want to install @angular/cli

Tags: npm, debian-buster

I want to install angular to Debian10, but I have got an error:
[image]

Ok, I know the npm version is too old.

So I tried to install the latest npm with

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

command, but I have got same error

I also tried to install npm form npmjs.com with

```
curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh
```

command (with switches -O -L) , but an XML file with NoSuchKey errorcode had been downloaded.

[image]

What do I wrong way? Do I need to run these commands as root or with sudo?
Thank you.

Comment: Please share all error messages **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, keep in mind that Buster reached EOL in June 2022 - maybe updating to a more recent version of Debian helps?

Comment: Yes. you are right. I upgrad to bulleyes and now npm is 7.5 and node.js is 12.22. There is no error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your npm version is probably fine. But your Node.js version is too old. Go to official node.js website and download a recent version.

You will find [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases) the compatibles versions and for angular & node : https://angular.io/guide/versions

Comment: Hmm, npm 6.4.12 version belongs to version node.js 10.24 by link you sent.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved with upgrade Debian 10 to 11.